# Viterbi-like algorithm with a single observation

Tags: hidden-markov-model, markov-chain, metropolis-hastings

Consider a Metropolis-Hastings walk over an exponentially large, known state space S.  The proposal/transition matrix P is known, as is the target stationary distribution.  In fact, assume there is an efficient algorithm Propose_P(s,c) that, if provided sufficiently long uniform sequence of "coins" c, will sample according to the s-th row of P.  In addition, there is an efficient algorithm Decide(s,t,c') that, using uniform coins c', implements the Metropolis-Hastings decision to accept the proposed next state t, or reject it and stay at s.  Finally, assume that the walk will take exactly M steps, where M is fixed and known.

Now, you observe the final state of this walk, and are told the coins c_i and c'_i used (for Propose_P and Decide) at every step i=1,2,...,M in the walk.  Your job is to "reverse" the walk, and determine the most probable *initial* state.  Note that you do not observe any of the intermediate states on the walk, just the final state.

To keep things simple, say that Propose_P(s,c) is "invertible" in the following sense.  If Propose_P(s,c) returns t, then you can uniquely determine s given (t,c).  Under that assumption, there are always at most two possible ancestors to the observed final state -- the final state itself (the ancestor was the final state, and at that point some state was proposed and rejected), and some other state (the ancestor was this other state, and at that point the observed final state was proposed and accepted).  This is potentially true at every step in the backwards walk, but obviously I don't want to keep anything like 2^M paths alive.

I've come up with some ad hoc pruning methods, e.g. keeping (at most) the N most probable paths alive as the reverse walk proceeds, but I'm hoping to find some known, already analyzed algorithm for this problem.  Is there such a thing?

Note that Viterbi doesn't apply, because there's a single observation.  My skimming of the hidden Markov model literature did not turn up anything immediately useful, either.  There are results for HMMs with missing observations, but nothing like what I need, with only a single observation when the walk completes.  (This could be captured if the observation probabilities could be time-dependent, e.g. returning NULL as the observed symbol with probability 1 except at step M, when it returns the final state.  But I haven't seen anything like that.)

Anyway, if you are still reading, thank you for your time.  I hope that someone here can offer useful pointers!